# PhpRedis: unable to set timeout for write operations

Tags: redis, phpredis

I'm using PhpRedis 6.0.2 on a single instance and I have set 'read_timeout' and 'timeout' to 1 second.

Also, I have tested the values using the getter methods.

The problem is that I get execution timeout from PHP on set(), which means it is not respecting the timeouts set for Redis.

I suspect that 'timeout' refers to the connection timeout (could see that in the c code) and read_timeout is clear from its name.

If that's the case, anyway to resolve timeout issues on write operations?

Either from client config or redis.conf, both are accessible by me.